vs code connect econnrefused 127.0.0.1:51833
The following error pops up randomly(sometimes, the number is 51833 or 53052, or other random numbers), when I am using visual studio code running my deep learning python codes. I configured the vs code and my server through SSH. Everything went through very well several months ago. But now, I can only run my neural network successfully by chance.
Here is the popup

and here is the launch.json

How can i fix it?
Thank you
I have tried some other similar methods online, but they don't work.

you can have a look if the .db file for the workspace has exploded, you can delete/rename it to try a clean start, on Windows <user>/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/workspaceStorage find the right folder
